# center a view between two buttons

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout

[image: test]

Hi. I need to center two separator between buttons. That buttons are aligned without problems with auto layout, but i don't know how to align the two vertical lines.

Comment: Is this in a UIToolbar? If you are doing it in the interface builder I don't think you can. But it has dots on either side of it. You can count the dots and just make sure they are even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a view between your buttons.  Give it a clear background and pin it on the left and right to your buttons with a constant space of `0`.
2. Add your line view to this view and center it horizontally in its containing view.